# sparql rdfs:range returns nothing

Tags: sparql, rdfs, openlink-virtuoso

I am trying to run a query to get `rdfs:range` of different predicates. This is my query:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

select DISTINCT *
FROM <http://dbpedia.org> 
where{
?s ?p ?o.
?p rdfs:range ?t.

FILTER (?p = <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/spouse>)

} LIMIT 10
```

But the query returns an empty table as return. I can run other queries on the `dbpedia` but it has this problem with `rdfs:range`. I am using virtuoso openlink for rdf storing.

[image: List of ttls]

I used this command to add them:

```
ld_dir('/home/dbpedia_ttls', '*.ttl', 'http://dbpedia.org');
```

Comment: I can not reproduce this. If I run your exact query, copy-pasted, against the DBPedia SPARQL endpoint at http://dbpedia.org/sparql, I get back a result with 10 solutions in it.

Comment: works for me too, i.e. instantly returns 10 rows. by the way, why the `?s ?p ?o` triple pattern? Can make the query much slower, so maybe you got an empty result because of the Virtuoso anytime feature which returns whatever it found in a given time. and if the endpoint was busy when you trid, this could have happened.

Comment: Thanks. So why it doesn't work on my local machine? Is there a problem with my virtuoso? do I need to do some configurations? Actually I can run other queries on dbpedia but it seems it has problem with rdfs.

Comment: it's the first time that you mention a local Virtuoso on your machine ... you always say, "run on DBpedia" - you know, most people assume that you're using the public SPARQL endpoint.

Comment: so, did you load the whole DBpedia dataset? That includes schema **and** instance data? And did you load both into the graph `http://dbpedia.org` ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention it on my question. No I loaded some ttls on my local virtuoso. I add an image form the list.

Comment: So the reason it doesn't work on your local machine is that you haven't loaded all the same data there that is found on the public DBpedia endpoint. A graphic image of files is hard to process. If you want people to tell you which additional files you need to load, you should provide a textual list. Better, you should just load everything, or use the public endpoint for this phase of learning.